# Is a TransactionScope appropriate to include side effects in the Entity Framework transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

Imagine the following operation using Entity Framework 6:

```
// operations on some entities

// send an email
// write to a file

db.SaveChanges();
```

If `db.SaveChanges();` fails, the email shouldn't be delivered, and the file shouldn't be written to. Am I correct in understanding that I would need to wrap all the code in a `TransactionScope` to achieve this behaviour? Like so:

```
using(var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // operations on entities here

    // send an email
    // write to a file

    db.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because you have   problems:

- Email is not transnational. So you CAN handle this by writing a Compensating Resource Manager that only sends the email on commit - with a new API. But if you send the email via SMTP it is sent - the mail server will not care about your transaction.
- File - well, transcriptional NTFS is officially retired ;) But you could use that. A CRM (Compensating Resource Manager) and a file backup at begin could handle this though.

So, generally - that approach is valid, but your two cases are really bad.

In this particular case I would likely use separate queued business transactions controlled via SQL Broker (or MSMQ) to start the other 2 operations once the commit is done.

Comment: So I should schedule side effects to be run by a separate worker through a message queue that supports transactions, such as Azure Service Bus, in order to make the above approach a valid *and good* one?

Comment: Yes. Because what you have here is a BUSINESS transactiton. The good approach to this goes through messaging or a workflow - not a System.Transaction instance. This allows compensating. Business tx are often complex and take a long time. I would possibly go with a workflow component if the scenario goes even more complex.